# bootstrap, have 4 column-md-3 of just images, how to remove spacing inbetween imgs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used the Bootstrap `col-md-3` to display 4 images at full width, but there is some white space that is inbetween each of the images. How do I remove this white space? Included is code and screenshot.

```html
<div class=".container-fluid">
  <div class="set4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h2>Past Events</h2>
        <div class="button1">
          <a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">ALL EVENTS</a><a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">CORPORATE</a><a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">WEDDING</a>
          <a
          class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">COMMUNITY</a><a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">+</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="demo-content1">
      <img src="images/pastevent1.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="images/pastevent2.png">
    <div class="demo-content1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="images/pastevent3.png">
    <div class="demo-content1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="images/pastevent4.png">
    <div class="demo-content1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You have to customize the padding or margins

Comment: would it be .demo-content1 img { padding:0;  margin:0;   } am i even attempting it correctly

Answer (score -1):

`padding:0` should do the trick, but you may need to use `!important` to over-ride previous formatting:

```
.col-xs-3 {padding:0 !important;}
```

In your case, you would put it on the `.col-md-3` selector, if that is what you are using. I had to change it to `.col-xs-3` for the more narrow SO code snippet environment.

Remember that there are multiple places where CSS is styled. For example, bootstrap comes pre-styled and you often need to over-ride that pre-styling.

A good tool to use is the Dev Tools (press F12 when viewing page). Learn how to check/change styling on the fly. It is life changing.

```css
.col-xs-3 {padding:0 !important;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class=".container-fluid">
  <div class="set4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h2>Past Events</h2>
        <div class="button1">
          <a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">ALL EVENTS</a><a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">CORPORATE</a><a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">WEDDING</a>
          <a
          class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">COMMUNITY</a><a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">+</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="demo-content1">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="demo-content1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="demo-content1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="demo-content1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey i tried your code and used verbatim and still got the white lines inbetween the images, any other ideas?

Comment: See [this post for further ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36947630/1447509). If that doesn't help you to solve it, you can consider posting your actual site URL in a comment, get help, and delete the comment later *(note the X that appears at right when you hover over your name at end of a comment).*