# HTML form blocked, cannot enter any text

Tags: php, html, css, forms

Hi for some reason all of a sudden I am unable to enter any text into a html form. It worked earlier and now it doesn't. I've been using HTML, CSS and PHP to write to database.  Any ideas anyone? It happened to me earlier because I set the some z value to -1 or something but i've since fixed that and now it's happened again somehow.

When I tab through the form I can enter text but when I hover over the text areas no cursor is shown.

```
<form action="dashboard.php" method="post">

    <div class="label"><span>Date </span><input type='date' class="datefield" name='date' /></div>

    <div class="label"><span>Department </span><input type="text" class="department" name="dept" value="" /></div>

    <div class="label"><span>Severity </span>
        <select name='seve' class="selectfield1">
                <option value="priority">Select</option>
                <option value="urgent">Urgent</option>
                <option value="high">High</option>
                <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="low">Low</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="label"><span>Status </span>
        <select name='stat' class="selectfield2">
                <option value="status">Select</option>
                <option value="progress">In progress</option>
                <option value="assigned">Assigned</option>
                <option value="completed">Completed</option>
                <option value="Delayed">Delayed</option> 
        </select>
    </div>

   <div class="label"><span>Assigned To </span><input type="text" class="assignedto" name="assi" value="" /></div>

    <div class="label"><span>Due By </span><input type="datetime-local" class="dueby" name="dueby"></div>

    <div class="label"><span>Description </span><textarea name="desc" class="description"></textarea></div>

    <div><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log Incident" /></div>
</form>
```

And the CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300); /* Here we import a font from Google's API in order to use it in our project as the default font. */

.form_heading{

font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
margin-bottom: 25px;
font-size: 25px;
padding-bottom: 7px; /* This block of CSS code designs the "Log Incidents" heading */
}

.dash_style {

position: relative;
top: 55px;
left: 200px;
}
.dash_style div{
display: block;
margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px; /* This block of CSS code decides on the spacing between all the boxes and their labels. */
}
.dash_style div > span{
width: 100px;
font-weight: bold;
float: left;
padding-top: ;
padding-right: 5px;
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif; /* This block of CSS code designs the labels and decided how far away the boxes will be  */
}


.dash_style input.datefield{
width: 10%; /* This block of CSS code just changes the width of the data field box. */

}

.dash_style input.department, 
.dash_style input.assignedto,
.dash_style .input-field3,

.dash_style .selectfield
.dash_style .selectfield2{
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
padding: 7px;
outline: none; /* This block of CSS code selects the different boxes by their specidied class and gives them a new look. */

}

.dash_style .description{
height:60px;
width: 20%; /* Here we decided how wide and tall the text area for the Incident Description will be */
}
.dash_style input[type=submit],
.dash_style input[type=button]{
border: none;
padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
width: 150px;
background: #336699;
color: #fff;
font-size: 15;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px; /* This block of CSS code designs "Log Incident" button */
}
.dash_style input[type=submit]:hover,
.dash_style input[type=button]:hover{
background: #EA7B00;
color: #fff; /* The "Log Incident" button's background colour and hover effect are created here */

}
```

Comment: Why don't you post the code relevant to the textbox?

Comment: Code? how can we debug the problem with no code to view? Maybe magical goblins decided to block your site? we need code! and if you want to show us a link, that helps too

Comment: Yes, please post an example so we can see. Without it we can offer no help.

Comment: Code posted in the question now

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with this code

Comment: I tried your code in a JSFIDDLE (https://jsfiddle.net/p4gL31cz/) and could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm doing this locally on my system. It won't let me even click a selector. Nothing works.

Comment: When I get rid of <span> tags, it works but then it isn't aligned nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can figure this out on your own by right-clicking on the desired element and choosing `inspect element` from the context menu.

This will pop-up the Developer Tools app, now built into Chrome, Firefox and Opera (slightly different in each one. I, for example, prefer Chrome's Dev Tools).

You will be looking on the `Elements` tab, and at the `Styles` pane. Note that you can experiment by adding/disabling CSS *on the fly!* Incredibly useful tool.

Read this post about how to use it, or search YouTube for a video:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

---

You will notice that it works fine in the below Stack Code Snippet. Probably, something else on your page is interfering -- and you are likely on the right track with the z-index.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300); /* Here we import a font from Google's API in order to use it in our project as the default font. */

.form_heading{

  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 7px; /* This block of CSS code designs the "Log Incidents" heading */
}

.dash_style {

  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
  left: 200px;
}
.dash_style div{
  display: block;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px; /* This block of CSS code decides on the spacing between all the boxes and their labels. */
}
.dash_style div > span{
  width: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding-top: ;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif; /* This block of CSS code designs the labels and decided how far away the boxes will be  */
}


.dash_style input.datefield{
  width: 10%; /* This block of CSS code just changes the width of the data field box. */

}

.dash_style input.department, 
.dash_style input.assignedto,
.dash_style .input-field3,

.dash_style .selectfield
.dash_style .selectfield2{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 7px;
  outline: none; /* This block of CSS code selects the different boxes by their specidied class and gives them a new look. */

}

.dash_style .description{
  height:60px;
  width: 20%; /* Here we decided how wide and tall the text area for the Incident Description will be */
}
.dash_style input[type=submit],
.dash_style input[type=button]{
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #336699;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px; /* This block of CSS code designs "Log Incident" button */
}
.dash_style input[type=submit]:hover,
.dash_style input[type=button]:hover{
  background: #EA7B00;
  color: #fff; /* The "Log Incident" button's background colour and hover effect are created here */

}
```

```html
<form action="dashboard.php" method="post">

  <div class="label"><span>Date </span><input type='date' class="datefield" name='date' /></div>

  <div class="label"><span>Department </span><input type="text" class="department" name="dept" value="" /></div>

  <div class="label"><span>Severity </span>
    <select name='seve' class="selectfield1">
      <option value="priority">Select</option>
      <option value="urgent">Urgent</option>
      <option value="high">High</option>
      <option value="medium">Medium</option>
      <option value="low">Low</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="label"><span>Status </span>
    <select name='stat' class="selectfield2">
      <option value="status">Select</option>
      <option value="progress">In progress</option>
      <option value="assigned">Assigned</option>
      <option value="completed">Completed</option>
      <option value="Delayed">Delayed</option> 
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="label"><span>Assigned To </span><input type="text" class="assignedto" name="assi" value="" /></div>

  <div class="label"><span>Due By </span><input type="datetime-local" class="dueby" name="dueby"></div>

  <div class="label"><span>Description </span><textarea name="desc" class="description"></textarea></div>

  <div><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log Incident" /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I see that it works there but for some reason it won't work locally for me.

Comment: If you cannot figure it out using Dev Tools, then you might consider posting your actual site URL in a comment, get help, and delete the comment later *(note the X that appears at right when you hover over your name at end of a comment).*

Comment: I'm developing it locally, so i don't have a URL apart from my own local host. I can however somehow upload the files to dropbox if that would work?